# How to run a for loop through every object of a class in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a game in visual studio forms application, I need to know how to run a for loop through every object in my class named "junction".
I'm hoping the code will look something like this (pseudo code)

For each object in junction:
   if currentjunction.coordinates==Desiredcoordinates:
      a function is called
      break
next object in class

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `foreach` [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in). This loop works with collections, and any class which implements the `IEnumerable` interface.

There's not enough information in the question, so here's how to use `foreach` in 2 most common scenarios.

## If your class contains a collection of objects

Let's call it simply `Items`. Then you should do something like this:

```
foreach (var currentJunction in junction.Items)
{
    if (currentJunction.Coordinates == desiredCoordinates)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

## If your class is a collection

Then you should do something like this:

```
foreach (var currentJunction in junction)
{
    if (currentJunction.Coordinates == desiredCoordinates)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should precise your question.

*"I need to know how to run a for loop through every object in my class named "junction"."*

Do you mean: I need to know how to iterate through a collection of objects of Type junction?

Your pseudo-code is ambiguous too, a first correction would be:

```
for each (junction in junctions){ 
  if (junction.coordinates==Desiredcoordinates){
    myMethod(junction);
  }
 }
```

where junctions is an array of objects of Type junction and myMethod the method called if the condition is true...